# Population JavaFX listView with ProcessBuilder results

Tags: java, listview, javafx, terminal, processbuilder

i am try to populate javaFX listView with process builder results. i could fill listView but
i want to do; smooth display of the columns like terminal, can any one help  me?

My execute command codes:

```
public List<String> executeCommand(String[] command, boolean joption) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.command(command);
    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((reader.hasNextLine())) {
            output.add(reader.nextLine());
        }
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```

and

```
@FXML
private void searchImage(ActionEvent event) {
    ObservableList<String> images = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    final String imageName = searchImage.getText();
    String[] command = {"docker", "search", imageName};
    CalistirShellCommand calistir = new CalistirShellCommand();
    images = FXCollections.observableArrayList(calistir.executeCommand(command, true));
    listView.setItems(images);
    System.out.println("bitti");
}
```

[Terminals Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFNJM.jpg)

[when codes run, listView's picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54kdD.jpg)

Comment: Wouldn’t a `TableView` be better for this?

Comment: yes. but i couldnt split results as columns because result is string. and i dont have any idea if linux bash command results string contains any regex.

Comment: It’s either tab-delimited or fixed-width columns, so you can fairly easily parse the output (if it’s fixed-width you can determine the column width from the header line). Write a `Container` class and parse each line to an instance of that class, and use those objects to populate a `TableView`.

Comment: I am having problems at that point. with what criteria can I split the current string. pls look at pics

Comment: You first need to determine whether the output contains spaces or tabs (which you can do, e.g. by dumping the output to a file and opening it in a text editor). IIRC docker outputs this as “fixed-width” columns with spaces. If that’s the case you can first read the header line and get the position of each column (`int idIndex = header.indexOf(“CONTAINER ID”) ;`, `int imageIndex = header.indexOf(“IMAGE”) ;`, etc). Then split each line in the output from those values: `String id = line.substring(idIndex, imageIndex) ;` etc.

Comment: (If it's tab-delimited, then of course you can just do `line.split("\t")`.)

Comment: Thanks to your guidance, I solved the problem. Thank you very much James_D.